# Laravel authentication check returns false after log in

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to register a user in my application and log him in automatically after successfully registering.

What i'm doing:

Sending an HTTP request from the front-end using axios:

```
    register() {
        this.loading = true 
        axios.post('/api/v1/list/register', {
            email: this.data.email, 
            password: this.data.password
        }).then((re) => {
            this.loading = false
        })
    }
```

Back-end controller:

```
public function register() {

    $data = request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:7',],
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);


    Auth::login( $user );

    return response()->json([
        'user' => Auth::user(), 
    ]);
}
```

The user get's registered successfully and the server returns the user just fine, although when i refresh the page `Auth::check()` returns false as a result to display the register page again

```
<list-property :auth="{{ json_encode(Auth::check()) }}"></list-property>

@if(!Auth::check())
<login-dialog></login-dialog>
@endif
```

Routes web.php file

```
Route::get('/list-property', [App\Http\Controllers\MainController::class, 'listProperty']);
```

I used FILESYSTEM_DRIVER file and database, both had the same issue, what could be the problem?

Comment: For now i modified the default authentication controllers which made it work, although i really want to know what I'm doing wrong and why it returns false in the authentication check when i refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be experiencing the same issue, the registration was happening through an API route which is incorrect, API routes are stateless, i moved the registration method inside web.php and it worked just fine.